# File not found exeption Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to coding and I am making a app for a subjet in school, but a error just appeared and I dont know what to do:

Here is the error:

update failed for AnAction(com.intellij.execution.ExecutorRegistryImpl$ExecutorAction) with ID=Run
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\cynav\AndroidStudioProjects\TheAlarm\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file\debug....\apk\debug\output-metadata.json

It says that it doesn´t finds a file, but the file its still there and also, I am using kotlin but there seems to be some thing of java or I dont know.

Answer (score 8):

first sync gradle

[image]

then clean project

[image]

if not work ask clearly and share your code or screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Just click on `Build` -> `Clean Project`

Comment: If it works, you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete output-metadata.json and try to build app (.apk) again